# What does 「コロリ、コロリと」 mean?

Tags: onomatopoeia

It's my first time asking a question in this website so I hope I'll be as clear as possible.

I'm new at learning Japanese and I'm reading a book containing the phrase 「コロリ、コロリと」. It is impossible for me to understand. I tried looking it up on google but I couldn't find any proper explanation about it.

Could someone please explain it to me? Here's the entire sentence

> マエダさんは、**コロリ、コロリと**いうところで、うしろを向いてグルグルと首をまわしはじめます。

Comment: If you had provided more context or a description of the scene, you would have received an answer many hours ago.  Careful answerers would hesitate to answer this question as is.

Comment: I see. Sorry for that, I'll be more careful from now on considering the fact that I'm no more than an amateur in Japanese. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Yuya Could you at least provide a sentence or two right before this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native Japanese speaking. It sounds weird to me because we use コロリ in a situation like

> 「彼はころっと死んでしまった。」
>   ("He was killed easily.")

or something like that.

And we don't use this word too much. You don't have to care about this because this usage is incorrect.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! And sorry if I didn't answer earlier. If the sentence isn't correct, then I won't search much further its meaning.

Comment: Okay. Yup, that's better:)